# How can i echo the last record php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

For a project a need the echo the last 4 database records. I have a script that show all the records but I need only the last 4. Can someone help me?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","test","test");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM formulier");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>tafel</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['tafel'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: just add "limit 4" (and "order by ..." if you need to specify a field for order) in the mysql query.

Comment: It is inconceivable that a project would employ a deprecated API

Comment: Do you have a column that can be used to check for the timeline or the order of the data?

Comment: Nanocv, Thanks! SELECT * FROM formulier LIMIT 4"); is for the first 4 records.I need the last 4 records.

SELECT * FROM your_dataBase ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4 does not work but thanks for the command

Comment: I made a mistake SELECT * FROM your_dataBase ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4 is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query...
SELECT * FROM `your_dataBase` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4